# RavenDb backup and restore

Tags: c#, ravendb

I need to take a copy of a Raven database that currently resides on a 32bit server 2008 instance and restore it on at 64bit server.  I have exported the data using smuggler.

However when I try to import the data at the other end I get multiple copies of every document.  As well as the latest copy the history for each doc is being restored as well.

So for my accounts document as well as

accounts-450

I also have

accounts-450/revisions/1
accounts-450/revisions/2

And so on.

Can anyone advise me how to get rid of these?

Thanks

---

Solved

Turns out import from a db with the Versioning bundle works much better when the target db has the bundle installed.

Comment: Please mark an answer as such, or create a new answer and mark it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Which build of RavenDB are you using? If I remember correctly there was an issue some time ago when backing up/restoring a database and using the Versioning bundle.

Comment: thanks Thomas, turns out I was being pretty slow and had not included the versioning bundle in the target db.